# Is it possible to reference field from Logs Scope then transform data to Trace scope on OTEL Collector Processors

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

Recently I had experimented with OTLP for learning I had try on using Opentelemetry auto-Instrument for tracing + logs. I would like to reference field from OTEL Logs format below as you can see in my picture field was inside ***"scopeLogs[1].logRecords[0].body.stringValue"***

**The reason I want to extract Logs field because I may have important data in that Logs Field which is printing at Standard Output but Tracing context was not had sufficient Business data.**

Now I can tracing technical stuff like HTTP Method, Path, Container Name, Kubernetes detail which is quite awesome however **I would like to inject my additional business context which is useful for Business Monitoring rather than IT Perspective only.**

As you can see here in my Logs Output **"Art Transaction=1234567890 I want reference this field from Tracing Scope"**
I would like to adding Logs value of that field to my Opentelemetry Resource Field with my Customize Metadata.
So if I had very long verbose logs information I may strip message by regex and create new field at Resource Level like

1. customLogsField derived data from some Regex pattern.
2. artID Resource field derived data from some Regex pattern.

```yaml
    # Contrib Extension
    processors:
      transform:
        log_statements:
        ## Pseudo Code 
        # 1. Extract Logs Message Field
        # 2. Save Extracted Logs Message to Some field which using later on
        - context: log
          statements:
            - set(attributes["body"], body)
            - set(attributes["body"], "<REFERENCE_LOGS_MESSAGE_FIELD>")
        - context: resource
          statements:
            - set(attributes["body"], body)
        trace_statements:
        - context: resource/ span/ etc
          statements:
          ## Pseudo Code 
            - set(attributes["artTransaction"], attributes["<REFERENCE_LOGS_MESSAGE_FIELD>"])
```

```yaml
{
    "resource": {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "key": "container.id",
                "value": {
                    "stringValue": "2a1f903bf157e542dd327f4db2d45172773e660b9b1738046b33b6fe4f47596f"
                }
            }
            // omit the data for example
        ]
    },
    "scopeLogs": [
        {
            "scope": {
                "name": "com.learning.controllers.SocketController",
                "attributes": []
            },
            "logRecords": [
                {
                    "timeUnixNano": "1692266462540000000",
                    "severityNumber": 9,
                    "severityText": "INFO",
                    "body": {
                        "stringValue": "sending message"
                    },
                    "attributes": [],
                    "flags": 1,
                    "traceId": "2fbbb25c3bb232b4cadc610a4a4a183f",
                    "spanId": "04fc0f19b697680f"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "scope": {
                "name": "com.learning.services.SocketService",
                "attributes": []
            },
            "logRecords": [
                {
                    "timeUnixNano": "1692266462541000000",
                    "severityNumber": 9,
                    "severityText": "INFO",
                    "body": {
                        "stringValue": "<REFERENCE_LOGS_MESSAGE_FIELD> Art Transaction=1234567890 I want reference this field from Tracing Scope"
                    },
                    "attributes": [],
                    "flags": 1,
                    "traceId": "2fbbb25c3bb232b4cadc610a4a4a183f",
                    "spanId": "04fc0f19b697680f"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "schemaUrl": "https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.18.0"
}
```

Currently I had no problem on changing/ modifying Resource Context on Tracing I can delete Resouce Field that I don't want to use on Tracing perfectly fine but **I don't known How can I reference Message from Logs then set it to Tracing Context for Resource or Span context.**

The end result that I just mockup should look like this one.
In picture we can using our OTEL Collector Processor to reference Logs Message then put it back to Tracing Resource Context.

**Opentelemetry Trace Resource**

```json
{
  "artTransaction":"<REFERENCE_LOGS_MESSAGE_FIELD> Art Transaction=1234567890 I want reference this field from Tracing Scope",
  "process.runtime.name": "OpenJDK Runtime Environment",
  "k8s.container.name": "socket-client",
  "telemetry.sdk.language": "java",
  "process.runtime.version": "15.0.2+7-27",
  "os.type": "linux",
  "service.name": "socket-client",
  "k8s.namespace.name": "demo",
  "k8s.replicaset.name": "socket-client-688cd87b55",
  "process.runtime.description": "Oracle Corporation OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 15.0.2+7-27",
  "process.command_line": "/usr/java/openjdk-15/bin/java -javaagent:/otel-auto-instrumentation/javaagent.jar --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp",
  "container.id": "9296562d7ec2b27983b05f542105e677f829e5c44acbe9896c610faaf5d9e98d",
  "process.executable.path": "/usr/java/openjdk-15/bin/java",
  "process.pid": "1",
  "k8s.deployment.name": "socket-client",
  "telemetry.auto.version": "1.23.0",
  "telemetry.sdk.version": "1.23.1",
  "k8s.node.name": "worker-4",
  "host.name": "socket-client-688cd87b55-ghb9t",
  "os.description": "Linux 4.18.0-372.64.1.el8_6.x86_64",
  "telemetry.sdk.name": "opentelemetry",
  "k8s.pod.name": "socket-client-688cd87b55-ghb9t",
  "host.arch": "amd64"
}
```

I had try many thing follow from transformer processor but it seem like didn't work. Most of them only work on Tracing Scope but cannot Reference Logs Message from Tracing Scop
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/transformprocessor#move-field-to-attribute